# DLE EOT n command makes the printer not to return anything

Tags: c#, printing

I am deveoping an application that communicates with a thermal printer by using ESC/POS commands.

According to documentation, when sending DLE EOT n command, printer should respond with the status, but it sends nothing and of course, application get stuck waiting for the reply.

This is the basic code in C#:

```
            try
            {
                int bytesSent = _socket.Send(new byte[] { EscPos.DLE, EscPos.EOT, 2 });    // Transmit Printer Status

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesReceived = _socket.Receive(bytes);

                if (bytesSent == 3 && bytesReceived > 0)
                    return !IsBitSet(bytes[0], 6);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex);
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Jaime

Comment: Do you know the printer receives the data? Is it hanging after `Send()` or in `Receive()`? Is the socket setup correctly (Do you actually have a connection with the printer)?

Comment: Yes... I have only shown a little fragment of the code....  the printer is initialized with ESC @ command, it prints, it sets absolute position... etc.... it acts upon every command I send, but DLE EOT n command. It hangs in Receive(). The fact that took my attention is that after the command is sent, the printer line feeds paper.

Answer (score 1):

Ehem.. I have found the problem.... I realized of it after the comment I sent here.... the EscPos.DLE constant was bad defined.

Thanks anyway
Jaime

Comment: did you find the solution?